# Anonymous class Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I create a anonymous class and pass it to  a thread and when I start the thread, it runs its own class..

Can someone explain, what happens to the object-r that is passed to the Thread?

```
public class Interface1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Cat");
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Dog");
            }
        };

        t.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: This would print out "Dog" since you overrided the run() in Thread.

Comment: It is ignored as you have overridden the `run()` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a `Runnable` as a constructor argument to `Thread`, it sets an instance field called `target`, which it usually uses when it `start()`s.

But you've overriden `Thread#run()` which is normally

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

with

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Dog");
}
```

In the anonymous class you've created.

So **your** code runs instead instead of executing `target.run()` where `target` is your `Runnable` instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code in [Thread.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29) -

```
634     public void  [More ...] run() {
635         if (target != null) {
   // target is runnable instance which initialized in constructor
636             target.run();
637         }
638     }
```

If you pass runnable object through constructor then it executes But here you override the run method of Thread class itself in your Anonymous inner class so it executed overrided method.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for `Thread`'s `run` method says:

> If this thread was constructed using a separate `Runnable` run object, then that `Runnable` object's `run` method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

The javadoc for `start` says it just calls `run`.  I don't see anything else that runs the `Runnable` object.  So I think we can assume that the only way to run your `r` object is through the `run` method of the `Thread` class.  However, you've overridden it.

If you want your overriding `run` method to also run the `r` object, consider adding this somewhere in your `run`:

```
super.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start a thread, java.lang.Thread's run() function is called. If you look at the source code of Thread.java, it first checks for the target, which is the Runnable passed in the constructor of the Thread class. This runnable is nothing but your class that has implemented the Runnable interface and thus overridden its run() function.

Since its the run function of the runnable now that is used, you should implement the logic inside your runnable. Keep in mind, that a new OS thread will be only launched by Thread class if target/runnable is not null, otherwise Thread.run() will execute in the same thread as the caller.